# Connected to database but information returns as bool

Tags: php, database, arrays, boolean, associative

```
mysql_select_db('fireworks', $conn);

$ask = "SELECT * FROM name";
$result = mysql_query($ask, $conn) or die();
while ($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
{
    var_dump($info);
    if (is_array($result)) {
        foreach ($info as $group) {
            print $group;
        } //end foreach
    } else {
        print "fail..";
    }//end debug
} //end while
```

I checked with phpmyadmin and the database `fireworks` CLEARLY has a table named 'name' in it. When I use `var_dump` it shows `bool(false)`. I heard that `mysql_fetch_assoc` is suppose to return false only if there is no more values left to print?

Edit: Sorry I should have included the full code:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root") or die(mysql_error());
if ($conn)
{
    print "<h1>CONNECTED!!!!</h1>";
}//end conn
```

Yes, I have information listed in the table, I checked the name of everything:

```
ID  firstName lastName
1   uraz      The pig
2   Billy     Henson
3   Jean      Jerk
4   Fat       Jerk
```

Comment: have you checked the table isn't empty?

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you're using? Var_dump shouldn't even be getting called if $info is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a logical syntax error:

```
while ($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
```

Currently this causes it to loop through all the rows, and when it's done you're left with the last value (false).

You should have:

```
while ($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

Comment: Also you later have... if (is_array($result)), which I think you mean to be if (is_array($info)) however that isn't needed as the return value of mysql_fetch_assoc is an associative array.

Comment: oh... dam i'm such a noob lol Thanks all! I took away the semicolon and all of a sudden all my information just appeared. Can anyone help explain how the semicolon does that?

Comment: The semicolon is the end of statement character.  You don't want the statement to end... you want it to continue and run the code inside the while loop so long as the condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have actually connected to a mysql database, unless you've left that code off. Also, if your table is empty or there are no more rows to fetch, `mysql_fetch_assoc` will return false. So, double-check that you're selecting the data properly.

Does your mysql user have SELECT permission? Is the password correct? Is `fireworks` the correct database name? Some web hosts will append your account username as a prefix to all databases, so maybe yours is `bnynn_fireworks` (except, with your account username.)

I'm not sure how this is actually possible though that you're getting false, it shouldn't even enter the while loop.

Comment: he's. if he wouldn't be, filling $resoult would fail

Answer (score 0):

You send the query, retrieve the first row and make a weird check:

```
$result = mysql_query($ask, $conn) or die();
while ($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
{
var_dump($info);
if (is_array($result)) // <--- :-?
{
foreach ($info as $group)
{print $group;} //end foreach
}else{
print "fail..";
}//end debug
} /
```

The [mysql_query()](http://php.net/mysql_query) function returns a **resource** or a boolean **FALSE**, but it will never be an array.